# Laravel Localization on the Fly for email mailer list

Tags: laravel, localization, swiftmailer

I am building a multilingual Laravel site.

I need to be able to mail clients in a language determined by a saved variable. This is what I do:

```
    $broker = $this->getSiteInstanceDetails($broker_id);

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($broker->smtp_server, $broker->smtp_port, $broker->smtp_encryption)
        ->setUsername($broker->smtp_username)
        ->setPassword($broker->smtp_password);

    // creating the Swift_Mailer instance and pass the config settings
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $mailer->send($message);
```

So I am using a swift_mailer instance to send my mail. The problem is I dont see a locale configuration. I would like to be able to set the locale per client (for example I might need to send a mailshot out to clients in multiple languages)

so as an admin, I have a locale setting of 'en', but I want to hit clients with, say, 'it', 'ko' and 'jp'

do I need to use `App::setLocale('en');` per client? for example, loop through my client list, set the locale to the current client, send the email, and then set the locale back to the admin? It seems messy to set the locale for the whole app, when I only need to get 1 view translated,.

any comments or suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass lang paramter as 3rd paramter to locale:

```
Lang::get($key, array $replace = array(), $locale = null)
```

So you can have set locale to `en` but you can check in DB that for user x you want to send email locale in `fr` so when using lang you need to use:

```
Lang::get('general.hello', [], 'fr');
```

and it should work fine. This way you don't need to change locale to the whole application but only pass custom if you want to get translation in language other than current locale set.

Comment: This is a usefull solution, but what if the mail is on the queue?